# How to use a package from .sty file with MikTex in Windows?

Tags: packages, miktex

I'm trying to use [this](https://satoss.uni.lu/projects/atrees/library.php) package in my Latex file. I'm using MikTex in Windows, and TexStudio as my IDE. I followed [these](https://miktex.org/howto/miktex-console) instructions on MikTex Console but I still can't get it to work. I did the following:

- I added ADT_web.sty to C:\Users\myusername\Documents\mytexmf\tex\latex\ADT_web.
- In MikTex Console -> Settings -> Directories, I added the directory C:\Users\myusername\Documents\mytexmf as  TEXMF root directory.
- Still in MikTex Console, I did Tasks ->  Refresh File Name Database.
- Then I closed MikTex Console, and opened up my .tex file in TexStudio. It has the call `\usepackage{ADT_web}` and then the following code that uses the package:

```
\begin{figure}
       \centering
           \pstree[levelsep=2.5cm,treesep=0.4cm]
           {\NodeA{Node A}}{
               \NodeA{Node A}
               \NodeB{Node B}
               \NodeAC{Node AC}
               \NodeBC{Node BC}
           }
   \end{figure}
```

TexStudio doesn't complain about not being able to find ADT_web, but it does complain about the calls to commands form the package:

```
Undefined control sequence. {\NodeA{Node A}}
```

If my code from the package is correct (it should be, I borrowed it from the documentation), can I conclude that the package isn't working? Or is there something I'm doing incorrectly, while I'm calling the package?

Thanks!

Comment: unfortunately texstudio's "summary" of the error messages makes them completely useless, show the actual error from the log file, that will show which command is undefined.

Comment: it would be _much_ easier to debug if you provided a small but complete document that produces the error rather than a fragment.

Comment: note you are using pstricks so make sure you use latex and dvips not pdflatex.